# Сжимаются ли данные в таблицах YDB?

Tags: ydb

Есть ли сжатие данных в таблицах YDB? Существует табличка с текстовой колонкой, в которой хранятся JSON'ы (десятки килобайт). Есть ли смысл самому их дополнительно обрабатывать (и хранить уже пожатые бинарные данные) или на стороне YDB всё уже сжимается?

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию сжатие данных в таблице не включено (не всем это нужно, дополнительная нагрузка на CPU), но его можно активировать:
И тогда сжатие данных будет происходить автоматически. После включения новые данные будут записываться в сжатом виде, старые, записанные до включения, останутся в исходном виде. Однако и старые могут быть сжаты, когда до них доберётся compaction.

В документации описаны: [Включение сжатия данных при создании таблицы (create table)](https://ydb.tech/ru/docs/yql/reference/syntax/create_table#column-family), [Включение сжатия на уже существующей таблице (alter table)](https://ydb.tech/ru/docs/yql/reference/syntax/alter_table#column-family):